# How can I be sure that I connect to a valid node?

Tags: wallet, node

How can an IOTA Light Wallet user be sure to connect to a valid node? What I mean is, in case someone sets up a Node that just pretends to be one, it could grab the seed.

Anyone knows how IOTA Foundation tries to handle that? Is there an official proven List of Nodes a Light Wallet user can connect to?

As far as I know it would be good if all the Light Wallet users do not only connect to the pre-configured nodes due to the high load of these nodes in case there is lot of activity.

Comment: The seed is never send. No matter how malicious the node is you connect to, your seed will not be revealed.

Comment: ? So in case I push the login button after entering the seed, what information is sent to the node? Is my wallet doing something with my seed before handling over the information to the node? 
I thougt I am directly connected to the node.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/584/whats-the-difference-between-a-private-key-and-a-seed

Comment: A bad fullnode cannot steal your funds. The worst it can do is not propagating your transaction on the network and/or attaching your transaction to bad tips.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to run your own fullnode and connect to it. There is nothing like a certification for fullnodes. IOTA is a permission less network.

This page : https://iota.dance/nodes gives you information about the state of some public nodes.

If your node is not listed there, you can use the [GetNodeInfo](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/reference) API to get the same information for your specific node.

It's important to check that the latest solid milestone is updated regulary and match milestone index in slack#botbox channel.

(note that if you worry about the security of your seed, it's important to use a [trusted wallet](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-can-i-trust-a-wallet), the fullnode don't have access to it)